# Starting and Stopping Apache with sudo

Tags: apache, debian, sudo

I can run `apachectl` fine as a regular user, but when I `sudo apachectl`, I get `sudo: apachectl: command not found.` Any thoughts? I have the apache /bin directory in my path.

Comment: It would help to specify that you installed it from source into /usr/local/apache, not the packages.

Answer (score 1):

From the fine manual:

> By default, the env_reset sudoers option is enabled.  This causes commands
>          to be executed with a minimal environment containing TERM, PATH, HOME,
>          SHELL, LOGNAME, USER and USERNAME in addition to variables from the
>          invoking process permitted by the env_check and env_keep sudoers
>          options.  There is effectively a whitelist for environment variables.

You could configure sudo so that the environment is not reset, or so the `apachectl` command is looked up in the correct path, or you could create a symlink to it in the standard path.